# I don't know the best way to logically go through a list and get each specific index information and add it to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code written, but right now it's hardcoded with a specific index. I want to go through a dataframe and for each individual index in the list, I want to get the sum

```
    sums = []
    test = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
         if row['subject_id'] == subject_id_list[0]:
             test.append(row['answer'])
             test = list(map(int, test))
    test_sum = sum(test)
    sums.append(test_sum)
```

if there are 5 subjects in the list, I want the sum for each subject and put into a new list of all the sums

Comment: Can you show us your sample dataframe and expected output? Seems like you can do this without having to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add another for loop? Something like,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   for item in subject_id_list:
        if row['subject_id'] == item:
             test.append(row['answer'])
test_sum = sum(test)
sums.append(test_sum)
```